# How do I include an icon once that can be used for both the executable and a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource, ico

I'm trying to use a single `.ico` file (with multiple sizes) for both the Application executable and a form inside the application, without including the icon in the executable twice.

I noticed this because my app (without icons) is 600KB compiled, and the icon is 300KB, but when I use both the app increases to 1200KB compiled, indicating it's being embedded twice.

Here's what I've tried:

### (1) Pick icon files using UI

1. Go to **Application Properties > Application > Resources > Icon** and use the "..." button to pick `MyIcon.ico` file.

   - Compiled exe is now 900KB
2. Go to Form Properties > Icon and use "..." button to choose `MyIcon.ico` file.

   - Compiled exe is now 1200KB

### (2) Use resource

1. Go to **Application Properties > Resources > Icons > Add existing file** and pick `MyIcon.ico` file
2. In form constructor, add: `this.Icon = Properties.Resources.MyIcon;`

   - Compiled exe is now 900KB
3. Go to **Application Properties > Application > Resources > Icon**, and choose `Resources\MyIcon.ico` (which is listed in the drop-down)

   - Compiled exe is now 1200KB

Clearly, it's still including the file a second time, not referencing an embedded resource.

### (3) Use Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon()

1. Go to **Application Properties > Application > Resources > Icon** and use the "..." button to pick `MyIcon.ico` file.

   - Compiled exe is now 900KB
2. In form constructor, add `this.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);`

   - Compiled exe is still 900KB, but icon is the generic "exe" icon from Windows, not my application's icon

---

Before I go deeper into this, am I missing something obvious? Is there a standard way to do this? Am I just not using `Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon()` properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, this is my oversight. Method (3) does actually work.

I was running this from the VisualStudio debugger, but didn't notice the `.vshost.exe` file gets a different icon -- which is what was showing up in the form.

When the compiled exe is used directly, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the necessary icon into the project you have to do 2 things:

1. Select Form and in the "Properties" select that icon in the "Icon" property.
2. Go to the Properties of the project and in the Icon field select the same icon.

When you build the project you will see necessary icon everywhere.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry not full answer and here we go:
You were right, it creates it twice, first one is ico file itself, the second one is base64 string in Form.resx file that generates when you add ico in the first step. So, how do fix it

First of all go to InitializeComponent() method, fine this.Icon string and change it to the following

```
this.Icon = new Icon(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "../../../[YOUR ICO FILE NAME].ico");
```

, then delete autogenerated Form.resx file.
Icon object here is System.Drawing.Icon. The file name I set for example, as you see it is the ico which is next to *.sln file. In the real case, it will be without going to parent folders.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did in (1) and it includes the ico twice, doubling the size of the exe. This is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I added the correct answer. But take into account that Designer will be unstable with this solution. It generates base64 string to *.resx file to let Designer work correct. I think you can install Icon for Form on the fly, not during initializing components. But I didn't work with Windows Forms so many years that's why there is probably some other good way to fix it.

Comment: Even with this method, you'd still have to ship the .ico alongside the executable, so you're still including the icon twice.